# Angular JS style guide when declaring variables

Tags: javascript, coding-style, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS and working on a project with "legacy" Angular JS code. The code is about a year or half a year old. I often see stuff like this:

```
var _link;
_link = "http://localhost";
```

Or:

```
var setup,
    _link;
_link = "http://localhost";  
// ...
setup = {
    link: _link
};
return setup;
```

This looks super verbose to me, but the guy who made this did it consistently  through the complete application. Is there any style guide or JavaScript convention for doing this?

I'm a Java developer and one of the first rules I learned was to always declare a variable where it is needed. No idea why it should be different here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples you gave seem unnecessarily verbose to me too.

However there is an important difference between javascript and Java.

In javascript, declarations are hoisted to the beginning of a function regardless of where in the function you place them. Scoping of symbols is different from Java.

```
function atest() {
    console.log(a);
    var a = 1;
}
```

Produces 'undefined' in the javascript console, in a browser. a is declared but not initialized.

But

```
function atest2() {
    console.log(a);
}
```

Produces an "Uncaught Reference Error" unless there is a property a on the default object, e.g. `window.a` in a browser.

Maybe your predecessor wanted to remind himself that the declarations are valid from the beginning of the function or script unit / file.

The idea of 'declare it where it is needed' does not work the same as in Java. Curly braces don't, on their own, control scope. A variable declared inside a for loop is visible outside the for loop, for example.

Yet it is still very common to see declarations where a variable is first used, in javascript.

You asked about conventions. There is a coding convention promoted by Crockford to put all declarations at the beginning of the function or file.

> "JavaScript does not have block scope, so defining variables in blocks can confuse programmers who are experienced with other C family languages. Define all variables at the top of the function."

From [Crockford's Code Conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

Crockford changed some of his views after he really came to terms with Javascript (see his evolving views on inheritance, for example). I don't know if he changed his views on declarations.

I can say from reading a lot of popular library code that it's not all that common to follow Crockford's advice about declaring at the beginning of a function. I see a lot of declarations at first use, and I think that's mainstream for Javascript today.

Answer (score 5):

It's almost certain that your colleague was bitten by a hoisting bug and decided to over-compensate.

My mom always cut off the ends of her pot roast before she seasoned it and put it in the oven. When I asked her why, she said that's the way her mom did it. So I asked my grandma what trimming the roast adds to the dish. She wasn't sure, but said it was important to do before you rubbed it down with spices. That's what her mother did, she said. The next time I saw my great grandma I asked her. She explained, "Yes. I had a small pot when your PawPaw and I were first married. I had to cut off the ends of the roast so that it would fit."

This code is your roast. Good thing you saw fit to ask questions and stop cutting off the ends for no good reason.

To my mind, no variable declarations at all is preferable:

```
// Forget all the setup and _link nonsense.
return {
    link: "http://localhost"
};
```

Be sure to compare style guides. Then pick and choose what works best for your team:

- [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml)
- [Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)
- [jQuery](https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/)

While you're at it, consider John Papa's and Todd Motto's Angular style guides.

- [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) (Angular Team Endorsed)
- [Todd Motto](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide)

Just remember, nothing beats common sense when it comes to coding styles.

Comment: "bitten by a hoisting bug" love it. My thoughts exactly. Also like your style guide links.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of angularJS, it's not compulsory to declare a variable.

Angular allows developer to code without it's declaration and never throws error for the same. this mean it is more intelligent so you don't need to go every time on the top of the screen to declare variable like other programming languages.

Example:

```
  function hello(){           
       //string            
       message = 'Hello World!!';
       return message;

       //object
       message = { };

       //array
       message = []; 
}
```